Proper direct image of sheaves along the inclusion of a locally closed subset $W$ is f.f. with essential image equal to sheaves with supp. $\subset W$
$\def\F{\mathcal{F}}
\def\Supp{\operatorname{Supp}}
\def\E{\mathcal{E}}$In B. Iversen, Cohomology of Sheaves, Section II.6, we find the definition of the proper direct image functor $h_!$ (aka direct image with compact support):

Given a sheaf $\F$ on a topological space $X$ and a section
$s$ of $\F$ over the open subset $U$ of $X$, we define
$\Supp(s)$, the support of $s$
$$
\Supp(s)=\left\{x \in U \mid s_x \neq 0\right\}.
$$
Notice that the subset $\Supp(s)$ is closed relative to $U$.
We shall be concerned with a locally closed subspace $W$ of $X$. This means that any point $v \in W$ has an open neighbourhood $V$ in $X$ such that $W \cap V$ is closed relative to $V$. The inclusion of $W$ in $X$ will be denoted $h: W \rightarrow X$.
Definition 6.1. For a sheaf $\E$ on $W$ we let $h_! \E$ denote the sheaf on $X$ whose sections over the open set $U$ of $X$ is given by
$$
\Gamma(U, h_! \E)=\{s \in \Gamma(W \cap U, \E) \mid \Supp(s) \text { is closed rel. to } U\}.
$$
The restriction maps of $h_! \E$ are induced from $h_* \E$, of which it is a subsheaf. We record this as a canonical monomorphism
$$
\tag{6.2}\label{mono}
h_! \E\longrightarrow h_* \E
$$
From the description of the sections of $h_{!} \E$ it follows that
$$
\tag{6.3}\label{stalks}
(h_! \E)_x=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
 \E_x & \text { for } & x \in W \\
 0 & \text { for } & x \in X-W
\end{array}\right.
$$
which in particular shows that $h_!$ is exact.

Until here, everything is clear to me. My problem comes from understanding the subsequent proof from the book (I changed notation $h^*$ to $h^{-1}$):

Proposition 6.4. The functor $h_{!}: \mathrm{Sh}(W) \rightarrow \mathrm{Sh}(X)$ is an equivalence between the category of sheaves on $W$ and the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ made up of the sheaves for which
$$
\F_{x}=0 \text { for all } x \in X-W
$$
The inverse functor is induced by $h^{-1}$.
Proof. For a sheaf $\E$ on $W$ let us record the following simple identity among sheaves on $W$
$$
h^{-1} h_! \E=\E
$$
Next, consider a sheaf $\F$ on $X$ whose stalks vanish outside $W$.
A close examination reveals that the adjunction morphism
$\F \rightarrow h_* h^{-1} \F$ may be factored through the monomorphism \eqref{mono} as
follows
$$
\F \rightarrow h_{!} h^{-1} \F \rightarrow h_* h^{-1} \F
$$
to yield an isomorphism $\F \xrightarrow{\sim} h_! h^{-1} \F$. $\square$

I understand why $h^{-1}h_!\cong 1_{\mathrm{Sh}(W)}$ (one can show this by reducing to the case of $W$ closed using the fact that the inverse image sheaf functor $h^{-1}$ commutes with restrictions to open sets). On the other hand, if we showed that the unit $\F\to h_*h^{-1}\F$ is injective with image equal to $h_!h^{-1}\F$, then the isomorphism $\F \xrightarrow{\sim} h_! h^{-1} \F$ would be natural, so we would get that $h_!$ is fully faithful with the desired essential image.
My question is: Why do we have a factorization $\F \rightarrow h_{!} h^{-1} \F \rightarrow h_* h^{-1} \F$ of the unit?
(All these claims are also stated without proof in Görtz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry II, Remark 21.2)

I remember being dissatisfied with the rigour of Iversen's treatment of this (and of other things, though it remains an excellent book). I can give a detailed account later

@FShrike That would be great! I just answered myself though haha. Let me know if you think of an alternative argument or improvement : )

$\def\F{\mathcal{F}}$Suppose $\F\in\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ satisfies $\F_x=0$ for all $x\in X-W$. First we show that $\F\to h_*h^{-1}\F$ is injective. Let $U\subset X$ be an open set containing $W$ and such that $W$ is closed in $U$. Factor $h$ as $W\xrightarrow{i}U\xrightarrow{j}X$, where $i$ is a closed immersion and $j$ is an open immersion. Then $h_*h^{-1}\F=j_*i_*i^{-1}j^{-1}\F=j_*j^{-1}\F$ by 01AX. Thus the unit $\F\to h_*h^{-1}\F$ identifies with restriction $\F\to j_*(\F|_U)$. This map is injective: suppose $s\in\F(V)$ is such that $s|_{U\cap V}=0$. Then $s_x=0$ for all $x\in U\cap V$. If $x\in V-U\subset X-W$, then $s_x\in\F_x=0$, so $s_x=0$ for all $x\in V-U$. Therefore $s=0$.
On the other hand, for $x\in X$, both $(h_!h^{-1}\F)_x$ and $\F_x$ satisfy \eqref{stalks}, hence $h_!h^{-1}\F$ and $\F$ are the same subsheaf of $h_*h^{-1}\F$.
